# Ubuntu 16.04 did not delete Vista.. why.?

Tags: system-installation

I downloaded Ubuntu 16.04 version, saved it to my formatted memory stick, as advised. Installed from the memory stick using Unetbootin, choosing to delete the OS I was on. I rebooted, as advised and chose the Unetbootin option from the two options given, and found myself on the Ubuntu homepage. Perfect... except that from there I cannot find my external HDD, to import all my bookmarks, documents and photos. So I rebooted, thinking it was a glitch, and came back to those same two options... this time I clicked Windows Vista, and lo and behold I'm back on Windows Vista.. although I chose to delete it when I installed Ubuntu. So, how do I delete Vista, and keep Ubuntu.?

Answer (score 0):

Run `gparted` (Gnome Partition Editor).  You can get to it by typing the name in Ubuntu's Launch button's search menu.

Gparted is a graphic disk manager.  Look for the partition `ntfs` and choose the option from the menu to delete it.

The partitions that you see named as type `ext4` and `swap` are partitions that are used by your Ubuntu installation.

Combining your question content and your references in the comments, you installed Ubuntu into Windows.  It appears you run the installation from Windows and install a `wubi` version of Ubuntu.  This is an image in your Windows.  Deleting Windows would also Delete your `wubi` installation.

You want to be able to take your data from Windows.  You can do all this if you perform a full install of Ubuntu.  You can do this by booting to the USB installation media and running the install from there.

To have access to your Windows partition, you might best use the `Install Along Side Windows` option.

When Ubuntu boots up you can user the file browser to copy your Windows files and documents over to Ubuntu.  After you are sure you have backed up all the data you want, then you can use `gparted` to remove the Window (`ntfs`) directory.  As mentioned in the comment, the `etc4` and `swap` partitions are the ones that is being used by `Ubuntu`.

Comment: I don't have partitions ext4 or swap. I have a huge 223GB NTFS partition and a 9.77GB EISA Configuration partition. That's all.

Comment: @LexiAngel How many drives do you have on your computer.  If you installed Ubuntu inside Windows (a wubi install) deleting Windows would also Delete Ubuntu.  You would most likely be better to boot to the USB and install Ubuntu from there.  That would be a full Ubuntu Install.  The install process would give you the option of deleting the disk and using Ubuntu for the entire disk.  It will make all the necessary partitions including Swap.  I'll update my answer to make this part easier to read and follow.

Comment: My computer only has the one hard drive, but it has only two partitions. I installed Ubuntu from an external memory stick.. after downloading it. It was the full version of Ubuntu 16.04. It gave me the option to delete Vista and I checked it, but it didn't delete. It also said it would partition the hard drive for ext4 and swap, but it appears it didn't do that either.  I've already saved everything I want to keep, so deleting Vista isn't a problem.

Comment: @LexiAngel Run the install and choose the `Erase disk and install Ubuntu` option.  It should be clear from the description on the screen that everything will be removed from the drive.  You'll have a fresh `Ubuntu` install.